# How to get php data into a html select?

Tags: php, html

I know that this question has been on multiple S.O. forums, but after reviewing, I seem to not be able to get the data elements in my phpmyadmin to appear in my html select. I am new to php, so therefore I am not very good at the fundamentals. Can anyone take a look at my code and tell me whats wrong with it? I am not getting any errors, just nothing in my html select.

Code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','Lab2_Database');

if($con-> connect_error) {
die("Connection Failed:".$con-> connect_error);
}


?>
<h1 id="header">Welcome to The Flight Club WebSite</h1>
<br>
<p>Select a Flight by Flight Number:</p>
<form>
<select> 
<option value="0">Flight Number</option>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT flightNumber FROM Flight";
    $result = $con-> query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['flightNumber'])?>" >
            <?php echo($row['flightNumber']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }               
    ?>
</select>
</form>


</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `while ($row = $con->fetch_assoc()) { ...`

Comment: Make sure your result has rows using print_r($result); then try echo $row['name'];

Comment: Also, you should use mysql_fetch_assoc($result) 
Or just foreach($result as $row)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = $con-> query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['flightNumber'])?>" >
            <?php echo($row['flightNumber']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
```

change with

```
$result = $con-> query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
        ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo($row['flightNumber'])?>" >
            <?php echo($row['flightNumber']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php
        }
```

variable **$get** is not defined i think

Comment: I tried that, but no data popping up in the select dropdown

Answer (score 0):

you are using mysql with mysqli object

```
$result = $con-> query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
    {
    ?>
```

change this to

```
$result = $con-> query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php